# To make nav in aside element

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I am having some problems with my own site.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9CIf.png)

I need to insert navs in index, but I'm hustling: the content doesn't show what I add.
Here's the code:

```
<div class="text">Indice.</div>
                    <div class="title">Contenuto Indice</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="scrollbar-outer">
                <li class="sub-off">
                    <a href="#1">
                        <div class="number">1.</div>
                        <div class="title">I bilanci aziendali</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                 <li class="sub-on">
                    <a href="#1.1">
                        <div class="number">1.1</div>
                        <div class="title">La costituzione delle società di persone</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                 <li class="sub-on">
                    <a href="#1.2">
                        <div class="number">1.2</div>
                        <div class="title">Il riparto utili e la copertura perdite nelle società di persone</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                 <li class="sub-on">
                    <a href="#1.3">
                        <div class="number">1.3</div>
                        <div class="title">Le variazioni di capitale nelle società di pesone</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                 <li class="sub-on">
                    <a href="#1.4">
                        <div class="number">1.4</div>
                        <div class="title">La costituzione delle società di capitali</div>
                    </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">SNC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SAS</a></li> 
                     </ul>
```

I tried different methods, and thyis is the last version

Comment: your question is not clear, please elaborate so we ould help

Comment: Basically, I would like put inside div "contenuto indice" hidden anchors  which appear when you focus in a li (1.4 "La costituzione delle società di capitali", for example) which connect  them with determinated subsections of main flow (or element), like for example the nav (image shows that the focus on the nav works, in reverse in sidebar doesn't). I hope to have been 
more understandable